# Express.js doesn't register some of the endpoints in other env

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is the code of my index.ts. I build it with TS "build": "tsc -p ./tsconfig.json && cp -R ./src/adminUI ./dist"

```
const db = mongoose.connection;
const app = express();

// TODO: whitelist
app.use(cors());
app.use(auth);
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'adminUI')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, _, next) => {
    console.log(req.path);
    console.log('Time: ', Date.now());
    next();
});

app.use('/api', endpoints);
app.use('/que', UI);
app.use('/admin', adminUI);

// START APP AFTER DB IS CONNECTED
db.once('open', () => {
    app.listen(process.env.port || 3010, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${process.env.port || 3010}!`));
    routesList.terminal(app);

    new Queue().start(+process.env.cronTime || null);
});

db.on('error', err => dbDebugger('connection error:', err));

// CONNECT TO THE DB
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${process.env.mongoAuth || ''}${process.env.mongoHost}/admin`);
```

When I run it locally I have all of the endpoints

```
      List All Routes        |
|------------------------------|
| Method |         URI         |
|--------|---------------------|
| GET    | api/items           |
| GET    | api/bank            |
| GET    | api/bank/:id        |
| POST   | api/bank            |
| POST   | api/bank/update     |
| POST   | api/bank/remove     |
| POST   | api/parser          |
| GET    | api/parser          |
| GET    | api/parser/bank/:id |
| GET    | api/parser/:id      |
| POST   | api/parser/update   |
| POST   | api/parser/remove   |
| POST   | api/test            |
| GET    | admin               |
| GET    | admin/updatebank    |
| GET    | admin/updateparser
```

When I run it on prod server with the same deps and node js, I get these endpoints

```
.-----------------------------.
0|index    | |       List All Routes       |
0|index    | |-----------------------------|
0|index    | | Method |        URI         |
0|index    | |--------|--------------------|
0|index    | | GET    | api                |
0|index    | | GET    | admin              |
0|index    | | GET    | admin/updatebank   |
0|index    | | GET    | admin/updateparser |
0|index    | '-----------------------------'
```

And funny but I don't' have api/ endpoint, it somehome redirects to /api/items

Comment: From what code you have shared, I cannot see how env settings would be preventing routes from registering. Could you perhaps share more code that could be relevant in fixing this issue? I can tell that a few variables like `endpoints` are not declared or assigned in what code you have shared.

Comment: Could you post the output of express with [debugging enabled](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html)?

Answer (score 0):

If this truly is an issue of env vars preventing the registering of certain routes, check everywhere that an env var is used near when routes are registered or attached to the app.

[Enabling debugging with express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html) might help you understand what's going on.

You mention the problem occurs when you run it on your prod server. What if you run it locally but first set NODE_ENV to production? If this is an issue of env vars, try narrowing down which one could be causing it by incrementally setting them in your own local environment.

My suspicion is that this is not an issue relating to env. It could be, but that seems unlikely.

Comment: Works fine on local with NODE_ENV development and production
will try to comment line by line :)

Comment: In case you haven't seen it, I suggest enabling debugging with express to see what's going on. Tryout the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Update - It looks like a problem was in some older files in the dist folder. I removed the folder and build the project again and it works. I don't know why and what was causing this, but let's make a rule to remove dist before compile every time :)